# Import Excel table in Visio 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, import, microsoft-visio-2013

I have an Excel that looks like this

```
Shape1 Shape2 Connection_Description connection_color
Shape1 Shape3 Connection_Description connection_color
Shape2 Shape3 Connection_Description connection_color
```

And I want to automaticall generate a visio chart from it with the connections. I have a few shapes that are all connected in some kind (30 Shapes, 50 Connections?) I only want a field and an arrow that shows a connection from column 1 to column 2. Every row represents one connection.

I have seen that Excel has the Data Option. But I dont get it to fit my needs. Any ideas?